# Count and apply condition to slice the mongodb array document

Tags: mongodb

My document structure looks like this:

```
{
   "_id" : ObjectId("5aeeda07f3a664c55e830a08"),
   "profileId" : ObjectId("5ad84c8c0e71892058b6a543"),
   "list" : [ 
      {           
        "content" : "answered your post",
        "createdBy" : ObjectId("5ad84c8c0e71892058b6a540")
      }, 
      {           
        "content" : "answered your post",
        "createdBy" : ObjectId("5ad84c8c0e71892058b6a540")
      }, 
      {
        "content" : "answered your post",
        "createdBy" : ObjectId("5ad84c8c0e71892058b6a540")
      }, 
    ],   
}
```

I want to count array of
**list** field. And apply condition before slicing that

if the `list<=10` *then slice all the elements of list*

`else` *10 elements*.

> P.S I used this query but is returning null.

```
db.getCollection('post').aggregate([
 {
  $match:{
       profileId:ObjectId("5ada84c8c0e718s9258b6a543")}
 },
 {$project:{notifs:{$size:"$list"}}},    
 {$project:{notifications:
            {$cond:[
                {$gte:["$notifs",10]},
                {$slice:["$list",10]},
                {$slice:["$list","$notifs"]}
            ]}
          }}
])
```

Comment: Try using `$addFields` instead of the first `$project`.

Comment: thanks @dnickless it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first `$project` stage effectively wipes out all result fields but the one(s) that it explicitly projects (only `notifs` in your case). That's why the second `$project` stage cannot `$slice` the `list` field anymore (it has been removed by the first `$project` stage).

Also, I think your `$cond`/`$slice` combination can be more elegantly expressed using the `$min` operator. So there's at least the following two fixes for your problem:

Using `$addFields`:

```
db.getCollection('post').aggregate([
  { $match: { profileId: ObjectId("5ad84c8c0e71892058b6a543") } },
  { $addFields: { notifs: { $size: "$list" } } },    
  { $project: {
    notifications: {
      $slice: [ "$list", { $min: [ "$notifs", 10 ] } ]
    }
  }}
])
```

Using a calculation inside the $project - this avoids a stage so should be preferable.

```
db.getCollection('post').aggregate([
  { $match: { profileId: ObjectId("5ad84c8c0e71892058b6a543") } },
  { $project: {
    notifications: {
      $slice: [ "$list", { $min: [ { $size: "$list" }, 10 ] } ]
    }
  }}
])
```